# Idiom of the act of doing something you know you'll regret immediately after

Tags: word-usage, idioms

1. Is there any idiom expressing the act of doing something you know you will regret immediately after?
2. Is the word "after" at the end of my first question necessary?

I will be grateful for any help/information you provide.

Comment: *Reluctantly, with a heavy heart, unwillingly, grudgingly, etc.* But I doubt there's a word with the specific implication that you know you'll regret it ***later***, as opposed to not wishing to do it ***now***. In the real world if you *knew* you weren't going to be happy *after* having done something, you'd already be unhappy about doing it *at the time*. Unless we consider quirky contexts like getting too drunk, in the sure and certain knowledge that you'll have an awful hangover in the morning.

Comment: Two related (but not exactly in the meaning I think you suggest) idioms came to mind: *digging one's own grave* and *buyer's remorse*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I would ask your first question:

> Are there any idioms for expressing the idea that you are doing something even though you will immediately regret doing it?

In this situation I might say things like:

> I know I'm going to kick myself for this later..
>
> I know I'm going to regret this but..
>
> Here goes nothing. (I think this is probably going to end poorly)
>
> Fuck it, YOLO. (considered vulgar by many)